# Creating bucket in Google Cloud Storage fails sometimes

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've been trying to create buckets in Google Cloud Storage following the guidelines from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming), using Java. I have a method that checks whether a bucket exists or not and returns a boolean, like this

```
private boolean checkIfBucketExists(String bucketName) {
   return storage.get(bucketName, Storage.BucketGetOption.fields()) != null
}
```

And, another method that actually creates a bucket, like this

```
public Bucket createBucket(String bucketName) {
    if (checkIfBucketExists(bucketName)) {
      System.out.println("Bucket already exists!");
    }
    return storage.create(
        BucketInfo.newBuilder(bucketName)
            // See here for possible values: http://g.co/cloud/storage/docs/storage-classes
            .setStorageClass(StorageClass.COLDLINE)
            // Possible values: http://g.co/cloud/storage/docs/bucket-locations#location-mr
            .setLocation("eu")
            .build());
  }
```

It acts a little weird sometimes when I'm creating a bucket. For example, I'm able to create a `bucket` named `name-bucket`, but not `namebucket`, even though I don't have an existing `namebucket` in my project. It gives me this error

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "myservice@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to namebucket.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "myservice@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to namebucket."
}
```

Is it so that, in Google Cloud Storage, I cannot create a bucket using a name that has been chosen by another user in their project? Is the reason why I cannot choose the name `namebucket` because someone else has already named a bucket like so in their project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the bucket names are unique for all users.

Check the [Documentation for bucket name considerations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#considerations):

> Bucket names reside **in a single Cloud Storage namespace**, which means that every bucket name must be unique. If you try to create a bucket with a name that is already assigned to an existing bucket, Cloud Storage responds with an error message. However, once you delete a bucket, **its name can be reused by you or another user when creating a new bucket**.

Comment: so you mean every google storage user use one storage namespace?
once other user use the name then i can't use it anymore? It seems strange, why not bind it to your Google account?